# Mapping JSON Result to an Enum in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have the following response from JSON service:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Student"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Faculty"
    }
]
```

And I want to map it to an enum:

```
enum Role: Int, Codable, Identifiable {
    case student
    case faculty
    
    var id: Int {
        rawValue
    }
}
```

But I am having trouble mapping since the array in JSON contains dictionaries.

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Show what you have tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: You need to think about your model. The implication is that the JSON is the source of truth about how ids map to names. If this is the case, you cannot use an `enum` because `enum` expects the relationship between the cases and the raw values to be determined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects have 2 member : id which is an Int and name which is a string that you want to use an enum for it :

```
struct Role: Codable, Identifiable {
    enum RoleName: String, Codable {
        case student = "Student"
        case faculty = "Faculty"
    }
    var name: RoleName
    var id: Int
}
```

example for decoding :

```
let json = """
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Student"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Faculty"
    }
]
"""

var roles = [Roles]()
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
   roles = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Role].self, from: data)
}
```

Edit: corrected type of name + coding key for enum

Comment: I would think the `"name"` key in the JSON would be used to select either the `student` or `faculty` case. Shouldn't your `name` property be of type `RoleName` instead of `String`?

Comment: You are right, I corrected my answer. Thanks

Comment: Now you need to include the custom `Decodable` code to map the `"name"` JSON key/value pair into your `name` enum property. But personally, I think the OP simply wants an array of `Role` enums versus your idea to create a struct with a nested enum. But the OP needs to clarify their question to be sure.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add the raw values for the enum keys which enable the correct decoding. BTW, the question is not very precise about this enum thing, so I try to make simple.

Comment: The id in JSON should be used to construct an enum. Student should be 1 and Faculty should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a custom encoder and decoder. Another issue in your code is that you are not specifying the integer value of your enumeration cases which should start with 1 (if you don't specify it will start with zero). So your enumeration should look like this:

```
enum Role: Int, Codable, Identifiable {
    case student = 1, faculty
    var id: RawValue { rawValue }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
    }
}
```

Then you can create a custom decoder:

```
extension Role {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        let name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        switch (id, name) {
        case (1, "Student"):
            self = .student
        case (2, "Faculty"):
            self = .faculty
        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                .init(
                    codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Invalid Role data"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

And if you need to encode it as well a custom encoder:

```
extension Role {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        switch self {
        case .student:
            try container.encode("Student", forKey: .name)
        case .faculty:
            try container.encode("Faculty", forKey: .name)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let jsonData = Data(#"[{"id":1,"name":"Student"},{"id":2,"name":"Faculty"}]"#.utf8)
let roles: [Role] = [
    .init(rawValue: 1)!,
    .init(rawValue: 2)!
]
let encodedRoles = try JSONEncoder().encode(roles)
print(encodedRoles == jsonData)  // "true\n"
do {
    let decodedRoles = try JSONDecoder().decode([Role].self, from: jsonData)
    print(roles == decodedRoles)    // "true\n"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```